# single-spa - how to load an Angular app without using SystemJS

Tags: angular, angularjs, systemjs, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I have an AngularJS version 1.4 application and I want to migrate to Angular 12+ . So I decided to use [single-spa](https://single-spa.js.org/) to integrate the new Angular App to the Legacy App.
I'm following this video [Single spa app with Angular and Angularjs micro frontends](https://youtu.be/ZJ8Cvo5UZdM)

In that video he is using [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) to load the new Angular App. Although SystemJS is said to be the recommended way I would like to know if it is possible to load both the legacy and the new app without SystemJS.  The new Angular app is created using [single-spa CLI](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/create-single-spa/)

This is the [repo](https://github.com/anuroopjoy/single-spa-legacy-angular) for the video

In the [**`main.js`**](https://github.com/anuroopjoy/single-spa-legacy-angular/blob/master/main.js) I changed to this

```js
// System.register([], function (_export) {
//   return {
//     execute: function () {
//       _export(
//         window.singleSpaAngularjs.default({
//           angular: angular,
//           mainAngularModule: "main-module",
//           uiRouter: true,
//           preserveGlobal: false,
//         })
//       );
//     },
//   };
// });

//create global variable
window.legacyAngularApp = window.singleSpaAngularjs.default({
  angular: angular,
  mainAngularModule: 'main-module',
  uiRouter: true,
  preserveGlobal: false,
})
```

In the [**`index.html`**](https://github.com/anuroopjoy/single-spa-legacy-angular/blob/master/index.html) I changed to [this](https://github.com/cmgchess/single-spa-legacy-angular/blob/teststuff/index.html). I managed to load the AngularJS app without SystemJS but couldn't figure out how to load the new Angular app without SystemJS.
I would like to know what changes I need to do to load the new Angular App also without using SystemJS